# iOS change number lines of label

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, label

I tried to code the number of lines for one label.

I did this :

```
[lblName setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-CondensedLight" size:19]];
[lblName setText:[objet titre]];
[lblName setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
lblName.numberOfLines = 2;
```

But it's not running, i've just one line...

Someone to help me plz ?

Comment: You should set your label's height as large. Can you show your label frame code as well? show your initWithFrame: or lblName.frame code. Also you have to set your label height as double of your font size to show two lines.

Comment: not running ? . we expect a detail question from you if you want a detailed answer in return

Comment: what frame is set? auto-resizing? auto-layout? not working how? add a screenshot and all configuration code.

Comment: Increase the height of label and set number of lines to 0, setting it to 0 will make it able to accomodate any number of lines in it but still the height has to be increased as per the text to be shown or you can decrease the font size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For set dynamic frame `UILabel` use following method

```
-(void) setDynamicHeightOfLabel:(UILabel *) myLabel withLblWidth:(CGFloat) width andFontSize:(int) fontSize
{
    CGSize myLabelSize = CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX);
    CGSize expecteingmyLabelSize = [myLabel.text sizeWithFont:myLabel.font constrainedToSize:myLabelSize lineBreakMode:myLabel.lineBreakMode];
    CGRect lblFrame = myLabel.frame;
    lblFrame.size.height = expecteingmyLabelSize.height;
    myLabel.frame = lblFrame;
    int addressLine = myLabel.frame.size.height/fontSize;
    myLabel.numberOfLines = addressLine;
}
```

In the above method you just need to pass your label object, width of your label and font size of text, such like...

```
[self setDynamicHeightOfLabel:lblName withLblWidth:passWidth andFontSize:19];
```

Comment: It's running, but i have a problem because below this label i have other text, and when i have two lines in my "label", the text touch the other text. Can i modify the line height of my label ?

Comment: for do it, you need to set lower font size instead of 19 OR decrease  Y-Axis of UILabel.

Comment: sizeWithFont is depricated

Answer (score 1):

Use this method:

```
- (CGSize)getSizeForText:(NSString *)text maxWidth:(CGFloat)width font:(NSString *)fontName fontSize:(float)fontSize {
    CGSize constraintSize;
    constraintSize.height = MAXFLOAT;
    constraintSize.width = width;
    NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize], NSFontAttributeName,
                                          nil];

    CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize
                                      options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                   attributes:attributesDictionary
                                      context:nil];

    CGSize stringSize = frame.size;
    return stringSize;
}
```

Set the `CGSize` returned from here as your `label` frame size.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the height of UILabel.
Just use following method to get the height of uilabel text and then set number of lines as following:

```
- (CGSize)calculateRowHeightAndWidth:(NSString *)text font:(UIFont *)font width:(CGFloat)width
{
    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, 9999)
                       lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return size;
}

    textDetailLabel.numberOfLines = size.height/height size of font.0;
```